# grunt bowerInstall not working

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs, bower-install

I'm setting up a new AngularJS project (first time for me) and I'm finding it very touchy...  Latest issue is getting bower to properly configure things in my index.html file.

If I just hardcode things to the googleapis, it all works just fine (example in the index.html file).

If I setup bower and do a grunt bowerInstall, it adds what look to be the correct lines in my index.html but they don't work at all. I get errors like:

```
Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://localhost:8081/bower_components/angular/angular.js".
```

and
`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <` for the angular files.

So far bower has been a royal pain... any ideas what's going wrong here? Thanks!

BTW, the simple app is working as expected and I've gotten some basic karma tests working.

**bower.json**:

```
{
  "name": "meanjs_book",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "homepage": "https://github.com/JESii/xxx",
  "authors": [
    "Jon Seidel <jseidel@edpci.com>"
  ],
  "description": "Rudimentary app from MeanJS Book",
  "main": "server.js",
  "moduleType": [
    "node"
  ],
  "keywords": [
    "MongoDB",
    "Express",
    "AngularJS",
    "Node",
    "HighPlans"
  ],
  "license": "MIT",
  "private": true,
  "ignore": [
    "**/.*",
    "node_modules",
    "bower_components",
    "test",
    "tests",
    "spec"
  ],
  "dependencies": {
    "angular-route": "~1.3.15",
    "angular": "~1.3.15",
    "angular-animate": "~1.3.15",
    "angular-mocks": "~1.3.15"
  }
}
```

**Gruntfile**

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

  // Project configuration.
  grunt.initConfig({
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
    uglify: {
      options: {
        banner: '/*! <%= pkg.name %> <%= grunt.template.today("yyyy-mm-dd") %> */\n'
      },
      build: {
        src: 'src/<%= pkg.name %>.js',
        dest: 'build/<%= pkg.name %>.min.js'
      }
    },
    bowerInstall: {

      target: {

        // Point to the files that should be updated when 
        // you run `grunt bowerInstall` 
        src: ['public/app/views/index.html'],   // index.html support

          // Optional: 
          // --------- 
          cwd: '',
          dependencies: true,
          devDependencies: false,
          exclude: [],
          fileTypes: {},
          ignorePath: '',
          overrides: {}
      }
    }
  });

  // Load the plugin that provides the "uglify" task.
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');

  // Default task(s).
  grunt.registerTask('default', ['uglify']);

  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-bower-install');
};
```

**index.html**:

```
<!-- AngularJS -->
&lt;script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">&lt;/script>
&lt;script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular-route.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">&lt;/script>
&lt;script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular-animate.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">&lt;/script>
&lt;script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular-mocks.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">&lt;/script>

<!-- bower:js -->
<!-- &lt;script src="../../../bower_components/angular/angular.js" type="text/javascript">&lt;/script> -->
<!-- &lt;script src="../../../bower_components/angular&#45;route/angular&#45;route.js" type="text/javascript">&lt;/script> -->
<!-- &lt;script src="../../../bower_components/angular&#45;animate/angular&#45;animate.js" type="text/javascript">&lt;/script> -->
```

</script> -->

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're getting that error when running `grunt serve`. The console message you pasted indicates that grunt isn't allowing JS files through. If a particular file type isn't allowed, it's replaced with index.html which is why it was transferred with MIME type HTML. Where did you get that Gruntfile from?

Additionally, I recommend using Yeoman to scaffold a basic Angular app. Check it out here: http://yeoman.io/codelab.html. It's very easy to follow and will make you more comfortable with using tools like Grunt & Bower.

Comment: Sorry, no. The command that was failing is `grunt bowerinstall`.